# Adding AJAX response to DataTables and getting DataTables warning

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datatables

This is my first time working with DataTables. I want to execute an API and add the data retrieved from it to a table using DataTables. Below is my code:

```
const showList_client_identifier_master = (client_name) => {
    startLoader();
    ajaxGet("API link",
      response => {
        console.log(response);  
        tbl.rows().clear();

        tbl.rows.add(response.map(a => [
          toString(a.id),
          toString(a.client_name),
          toString(a.organization_name),
          toString(a.carrier_name),
          toString(a.account_name),
          toString(a.groupnumber),
          toString(a.bin),
          toString(a.pcn),
          toString(a.area_name),
          toString(a.submitted_bin),
          toString(a.submitted_pcn),
          toString(a.submitted_groupnumber),
        ]));

        tbl.rows().draw();
        console.log('table updated.');
        initTable();
      }
    );
}
```

I know that I am getting the data in my response but I get the following error.

[image]

Not able to figure out what the problem is because I know that I am accessing the columns properly.

The response from AJAX is as follows:

```
0: {id: 123, client_name: "abc", organization_name: "abc", 
   carrier_name: "abc", account_name: "abc", …}

1: {id: 123, client_name: "abc", organization_name: "abc", carrier_name: 
   "abc", account_name: "abc", …}
```

If I view the full response of 0

```
0:
account_name: "abc"
area_name: abc
bin: "123"
carrier_name: "abc"
client_name: "abc"
created_by: "abc"
etl_created_datetime: "2123"
etl_modified_datetime: "123"
groupnumber: "abc"
id: abc
organization_name: "abc"
pcn: "abc"
submitted_bin: abc
submitted_groupnumber: abc
submitted_pcn: abc
```

My Table is initialized as:

```
    const initTable = () => {
    if (tbl) tbl.destroy();
    tbl = $('table').DataTable({
        searching: false,
        lengthChange: false,
        pageLength: 20,
        language: {
            paginate: {
                previous: "<<",
                next: ">>",
                first: "|<",
                last: ">|"
            }
        },
        order: []
    });
};
```

Comment: Remove the comma after toString(a.submitted_groupnumber), that's making an issue

Comment: @noobprogrammer I tried running the code after the change you suggested. Still getting the same error.

Comment: This may happen if you have mentioned an index number of column in bSortable or bSearchable which is not actually present. Check if that is the problem.

Comment: @VivekGondhiya where can I find this?

Comment: @VivekGondhiya I have added the init code for the table. In that Search is kept false.

Comment: add sortable field with value false, the name of 'sortable' field will be according to your datatable version.. try adding "ordering": false

Comment: tried it.. still the same. Is it possible if i create the rows first and then try to add the DataTables feature to my table. So what I would be doing is that create the rows dynamically (by creating one big string of all the rows and then appending it to the table) and then use $('#mytable').DataTable()